# git ignore a specified type of change to file by rule

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a repository which includes files that are generated when a third party executable is run. I need to track the files that are generated by this executable, to allow me to sync the executable settings between users.

Let us call this file "executable_settings.json"

The file can change in 2 ways:

1. A settings change that needs to be added to the repository
2. A run-time change which is generated every time that the executable is run and changes the file in a specified way that can be captured by regex  (e.g. "Edited On: XXXX-YY-ZZ"). I do not want these changes to be in the repo.

Is there a way to get git to automatically ignore changes to executbale_settings.json, according to a rule? I would like to find a way to have changes of type 2 not appear as changes to git unless there was also a change of type 1 at the same time.

Comment: No, git can only ignore entire files base on file globs.

Comment: Thanks @fredrik. I am wondering whether there is a workaround solution with git hooks? I don't have any experience with hooks, but I was wondering whether it might be possible to run a hook before git status such that:

     if (no "Change 1") 
     then(replace the "Change 2" with the text in the previous commit)
Is this something that is possible using hooks?

Comment: You can read about which hooks are available at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Hooks won't help here. A *merge driver* could theoretically help, except that it won't in practice either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way here is to use a smudge and clean filter.  These are outlined in the `gitattributes(7)` documentation, but to summarize, if you write an entry in `.gitattributes` like so:

```
executable_settings.json  filter=exec-settings
```

and then add the following to your config:

```
[filter "exec-settings"]
    clean = sed -e '/Edited On:/d'
```

then when you add the file to Git with `git add`, it will deleted all the lines which contain “Edited On”.  Note that this won't intrinsically prevent them from being marked modified by `git status`, but it will prevent those lines from being checked in.

Note that you can use a different command, such as `jq` or a script, that would filter out the entries you don't want.  Once you're happy with the filter, you should add `.gitattributes`, run `git add --renormalize .` to fix the files in the repository, and commit.

I should point out that this is generally local to your system.  There's no way to include this configuration in the repository such that it's automatically invoked.  This is because doing so would allow arbitrary code execution.  However, you could add a setup script to your repository that installs this configuration locally as part of your project.

Comment: Thanks @bk2204 I am giving this a try. But getting a bit stuck with the sed and regex. The "Edited On" is not on a single line so I can't delete the entire line. For the executable to run, I need to retain the string "Edited On". So I want to delete only the YYYY-MM-DD which is preceded by the string "Edited On". Could you suggest an edit to the clean command above?

Comment: You could try `perl -pe 's/(Edited On:)\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/$1/g'` (untested).  You can also do something similar with sed or Ruby if you don't like Perl.

Comment: Filters are magic....Thank you!!!

Comment: This is the filter I used in the end `clean = perl -pe 's/(Edited On:  )\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}//g`. The double \ was required to escape the \